# How can my apk be self-installed from website without an SD Card?

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I want to roll out a non-market apk to our users via our website. The users will go through the standard browser, type in the url, click an Install App button, and it should install (with their approval, of course).

Most of our users don't have an SD Card. Installing from adb is not an option.

I only know how to post my apk on the site and have it load to the SD Card and then install from another program like Astro File Manager.

How do I have the app install after the user chooses to install it from our website?  How is this done without an SD Card?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the phone's browser, download the .apk, then go to Menu/Downloads and select the downloaded .apk. As long as the phone has been configured to accept non-Android market installs, the installation screen should appear.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know this method so thanks.  But it doesn't seem to work without an SD Card.  Says an SD card is require to download the.apk

Comment: Apologies. If the user doesn't have an SD Card, then the browser is unable to download _any_ files (regardless of whether it is an .apk file or not). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198772/installing-android-app-without-sd-card

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no automatic way doing that without an SD-Card, but after downloading you can install it doing the following steps.

Connect your SmartPhone or Pad via USB. Go via Terminal/Console into the SDK path (SDK is required!) sdk/platform-tools/ and run

```
adb install youradkfile.adk
```

(note: on Mac type "./" without quotes before adb)

To find the app after installation go to menu, add, shortcuts, applications and select your app to have it on your desktop.